# Is it possible to convert Json to Parquet Without Hadoop.dll and Winutils installed in java

Tags: java, json, apache-spark, parquet

I need to be able to make a function and convert json array to parquet without installing and setting paths for Hadoop and winutils. It needs to be a very mobile function. The only ways I have seen it done are with the apache library but that all seems to need those external dependencies.

Comment: If you don't want to use the library and associated dependencies, then you simply need to recreate the file format in your application: https://parquet.apache.org/docs/file-format/ You could create your own implementation from scratch to mimimc the file structure/format, or you could copy the relevant parts of the code from the [open-source library](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/) (with correct licensing of course).

Comment: Do you know of a maven dependency that can be used to do the converion that is not apache?